# wrong path doesn't give error anymore in django

Tags: python, django

Before if I go to a wrong path django gives an error that there is no path by that name but now I can go to any url path even if I didn't specify that path.
and I noticed that before I was able to add new templates and everything was fine, now whenever I add a new template it shows an empty page with the navbar and the footer only without the new template.
but I'm still able to edit the old templates.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name=""),
    path('home/',views.home,name='home'),
    path('privacy/',views.privacy,name='privacy'),
    path('return/',views.returnP,name='return'),
    path('search',views.search_book,name='search'),
    path('contact_us/',views.contact_us,name='contact_us'),
    path('suggestions/',views.suggestions,name='suggestions'),
    path('books-list', views.bookslistAjax),
    path('<str:cats>/',views.CategoryView, name='category'),
    
]
```

Comment: The last URL in your patterns will match *any* path that has a string with only one slash in it. You probably need to change that path to be more specific - e.g., add a `cat/` prefix.

Comment: @solarissmoke that was the problem bro thank you <3